# Ember, my template doesn't update on property change

Tags: templates, ember.js

Why doesn't my template get updated when I change the property it is rendering? The [documentation](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/displaying-a-list-of-items/) states that `{{each}}` is bindings-aware, but there's obviously something to it that I am not aware of.

> Like everything in Handlebars, the {{#each}} helper is bindings-aware.
>   If your application adds a new item to the array, or removes an item,
>   the DOM will be updated without having to write any code.

Here's my controller

```js
App.MaintemplateController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  alist: ['foo', "bar"],        
  actions : {   
    addel: function(){
            this.alist.push('xpto');
            console.log(this.alist);
     }
   }
});
```

In my template I have the following code.

```
{{#each alist}}
    <li>{{.}}</li>
{{/each}}
<button {{action 'addel'}}>Add element</button>
```

The data is properly rendered, and when I click the button it does append elements to the property, but the template doesn't refresh. Why? How do I keep it in sync with my data?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your template is not updating because you are using plain vanilla javascript `.push` instead of the by ember provided `.pushObject` and `.removeObject` respectively. Ember by default extends the array prototype to make it play nicely in a binding aware environment.

So to make your template update you should do:

```
App.MaintemplateController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  alist: ['foo', "bar"],        
  actions : {   
    addel: function(){
      this.get('alist').pushObject('xpto');
      console.log(this.get('alist'));
    }
  }
});
```

The important line here is `this.get('alist').pushObject('xpto');`
Furthermore you should always use `.get()` and `.set()` to access objects in ember otherwise the binding mechanism will not be aware of changes made to the object.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This answers my question and solves this problem. However I was hoping there was a solution that would work regardless the data-type.
What do I do if instead of a simple array I have a complex object and need to use assignement to update some of its inner properties?

Comment: @Pico, glad I could help. Well in case of a more complex object you walk down the object tree and set it's properties, like: `this.get('complexObject.childOne.childTwo').set('name', 'foo');` makes sense?